# How to change theme programatically for specific controller?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, controllers, dynamic

How to change theme programatically for specific controller ?

I have to change theme for a particular controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set specific theme for all action of controller you can add in controller

```
protected function _construct(){
   parent::_construct();
   Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
    ->setPackageName('packagename') //Name of Package
    ->setTheme('default');// Name of theme
}
```

If you want to set for specific action then add below code at startup of action

```
 Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
        ->setPackageName('packagename') //Name of Package
        ->setTheme('default');// Name of theme
```

Check following example:

```
public function loginAction()
{
   if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

   Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
    ->setPackageName('packagename') //Name of Package
    ->setTheme('default');// Name of theme

   $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Login-Required', 'true');
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easy change the theme at controller using below code:

> ```
> Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')
>                     ->setPackageName($package)
>                     ->setTheme($theme);
> ```

Where *$package* is package name of your theme  like `rwd,default,base etc`.
and *$theme* is  `default,base,iphone etc` basic of package.

**Note**: You should call this code before `$this->loadLayout(),$this->renderLayout()` functions for apply the theme.

Suppose,you want change the ***`theme of contacts and want to apple default's package iphone theme use`***:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
    /* add themen here */
        Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')
                    ->setPackageName('default')
                    ->setTheme('iphone');
    /* end of add theme */

        $this->loadLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in action to set Package and theme for the action as following

```
  Mage::getDesign()->setArea(‘frontend’) //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
            ->setPackageName(‘default’) //Name of Package
            ->setTheme(‘modern’); // Name of theme
```

You may write the code in  layout handler to set theme as following

```
<reference name=”root”>
<action method=”setTheme”><theme>modern</theme></action>
</reference>
```

Happy coding